# use a buffer instead of serialization

Tags: performance, wcf, c#-4.0, serialization

i have WCF service in which many client are connected to him via callbacks
i saw that when i send to all of them the same message i have cpu peak due to the deserialization. is it possible to do one serialization and use this buffer to send it to all clients?

Comment: How do you know that serialization is the problem?

Comment: using performance monitoring - when the cpu was high all the threads were in the serialization process

Answer (score 0):

i think you can go ahead with singleton instance management as you are sharing same data across application. So one instance can serve you share data across the application.